# UIAlertController has larger font than system alerts

Tags: ios, objective-c, font-size, uialertcontroller

I have an odd problem.  I'm trying to display alerts in iOS 10 but when I do the font of all the elements is very obviously a different size to the system alerts.  This is most obvious on an iPhone 6/7 plus.

Has anyone else seen this?  Any idea how to fix it?  Its quite jarring.

Comment: Do you have any code messing with UIAppearance? It can sometimes mess up.

Comment: @Cyupa: Nope nothing ... just a simple vanilla UIAlertController.  No messing at all.